# Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot and transfer failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm new to maven and when I begin a spring-boot project, i face a lot of problems as below:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:pom:2.2.3.RELEASE from/to alimaven (https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public): Transfer failed for https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/public/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.2.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.pom
```

also, when i use other depedency, the maven cannot download it from my mirror, and my settings is as below

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>alimaven</id>
        <name>aliyun maven</name>
        <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <!--<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf> -->
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

why cant my maven download any jar from the repo?

Comment: Some sort of local or transitory network issue. The lib exists in the repo (I have confirmed that using the GAV search (group=org.springframework.boot, artefact=spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, version=2.2.3.RELEASE and look for the POM entry), so it should download. Start by commenting out the mirror and trying the download from central.

Comment: after changing my network, it cant work either, but when i use the maven repo instead of the mirror, it can be downloaded

Comment: The files seem to be in the repo, so I'm still guessing that its some variety of networking issue. Could be a firewall somewhere on your network(s), or some other type of block in china itself. I would strongly recommend sticking with the standard maven repo (central), or running your own.